# Temporarily storing Images on elastic beanstalk api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP API that will be hosted on Elastic Beanstalk. The user uploads images to this API. Once the API gets it, in PHP I store the file in a temp folder, then resize it to multiple sizes then upload it to an S3 Bucket.

It works locally but I haven't put this live yet. Is this possible to do once it is on an elastic beanstalk instance? I know I have to give write permissions to the temp_image directory when I work with it locally so do I have to do this when it's live on elastic beanstalk? If so, how do I manage folder directories on an elastic beanstalk? And will I have to do this every time I update my API?

Another solution I thought of is having a temp_image S3 Bucket and working from that?

Any suggestions would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticBeanstalk deployments are considered immutable post-deployment, so you will probably have to change permissions on your temp folder. Thankfully, doing so is pretty straightforward. The mechanism for performing operations such as `chmod` or `chown` is through configuration files, described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands). ElasticBeanstalk configuration files are invoked as part of a deployment, so the permissions should be applied automatically every time you update your API.

In your case, you would use something like this:

**.ebextensions/01-make-temp-folder-writeable.config**

```
container_commands:
  chown_folder:
    command: "chown webapp temp_image"
  chmod_folder:
    command: "chmod 775 temp_image"
```

Make sure you pay attention to your indentation - YAML files are very sensitive to whitespace.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll be trying this out today and will mark answer correct once I get it working. Looks like this is the advice I was looking for though.

Comment: Just a note for anyone trying to do this - the commands are run in lexicographical aka you want to name your commands like 001chown_folder , 002chmod_folder, 003another_command to make them run in order.